# Can the Location header be used for multiple resource locations in a 201 Created response?

Tags: http, rest

What is the correct verb and response to accept a batch PUT create and then return multiple locations? The Location header only appears to support one single Uri.

I assumed originally I could use PUT for a batch create and return an string array with a list of Uris, but in looking at the [specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30), that doesn't appear to be supported, but it isn't entirely clear either.

Are multiple Location headers permissible as an alternative?

Any advice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can have only one Location header field (and yes, it is clear from the spec).

That being said, PUT is for creating/updating a single resource. It seems that you're using it for something it is not designed for...

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. So we should be using POST for a batch create?

Comment: Yes, but the question still remains: in a batch create situation how does one return all the individual resource locations? A long-winded approach: compile those resource locations into their *own resource* and return a URL to *that*, but like I said, it's a bit long-winded.

Answer (score 5):

PUT can only create one resource, because according to the specification:

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload.

(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)

However, it is possible for a request with a different verb (such as POST) to create multiple resources and return a 201 Created status. According to the specification:

> The primary resource created by the request is identified by either a Location header field in the response or, if no Location field is received, by the effective request URI.
> The 201 response payload typically describes and links to the resource(s) created.

(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2)

So it is OK to return the URIs of multiple created resources in a 201 response to, e.g., a POST request, but the Location header may only contain one URI.

Comment: True, but you are citing an obsolete document.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988) introduces Link HTTP Header. It can be used for this purpose.